# libGDX Box2D SIGSEGV crash on Computer and Tablet but works on Phone

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

When i try to run Desktop (2 different comps one is ubuntu 64bit other is win10 64bit:
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9a74000078, pid=12442,
>   tid=0x00007f9a85721700

When i try to run on my tablet SM-T210 Android 4.4.2:

> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x7a041b40 (code=2), thread 13671

(Thread-476)

When i try to run it on my S7 6.0.1 it works fine.

I have tried to comment out every possible section of the code still no use. I made progress when i don't create any Body program compiles but the camera is Zoomed in and i can only see 6 dots on screen instead of a 8*15 dot matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was disposing shapes at wrong places i guess moving them solved the issue. Why does my phone ran it but my tablet didn't is still a mystery though.